# Keyword "Protocol" as function parametr

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, redpark

i have problem with function parametr. 
Im using redpark serial cable, and when its it connected the delegade method called,
[image]
but in function parametr called "protocol".
[image]

Is it possible to get value of this parametr?

Comment: just use it? `print(protocol)`

Comment: “protocol” is a keyword, so you must enclose it in backticks: ```print(`protocol`)```

Comment: @MartinR, thank you. Your solution works.